# Оптимизация сайта

Tags: оптимизация

У меня есть сайт. Весит он 3.6 МБ. Но грузится чет долго. От чего это может быть? Там не много скриптов. Паралаксы. И хостинг бесплатный. Может из за этого? Или еще от чего может быть?

Comment: Дай угадаю - hostinger?

Comment: 000webhost

Comment: Что значит грузится долго? Долго загружается сама страница? Долго возвращается вообще все, включая статику? Долго инициализируется яваскрипт?

Comment: @Fike загружается долго сама страница. Там большой лист идет. При загрузке грузятся отдельные элементы, а пара иконок или фоток вообще не грузится. Как будто сайт весит 100МБ

Comment: а как вы замеряете скорость загрузки? Экспериментально со своего компьютера? Или добавили в скрипты таймеры?

Comment: @samoilow, а что ни так с hostinger?

Comment: А не проще ли измерить время выполнения скрипта (microtime() вам в помощь). А еще лучше отдельных участков кода?

Comment: @navi1893 free.timeweb.ru

Comment: @navi1893 тест-аккаунт возьмите и проверьте. вот тут к примеру на 5 дней http://ukraine.com.ua

Comment: @M11, да кстати, очень хорошая идея! Почти любой платный хостинг предоставляет бесплатный триал период. Регайтесь и кидайте сайт туда. Заодно и преимущества платных площадок в живую ощутите, не потратив ни копейки и вопрос свой решите.

Comment: Люди, помогите пожалуйста. Сайт даже на платном хостинге грузится долго. Хотя весит 4-5 МБ! Помогите советами, с чего это так? Могу дать ссылку на сайт

Comment: 4-5мб весит одна страница? Это определенно много. Сожмите картинки. Все js в async

Comment: http://www.rusdigi.name/asinkhronnaya-zagruzka-skriptov-atribut-async/

Comment: Посмотрите что больше всего весит, какие данные, исходя из этого уже и плясать надо

Comment: @navi1893 css`ки лучше как раз таки загружать до отображения страницы, что бы пользователь не увидел некрасивый сайт без стилей. запихните все стили в один файл, удалите в нем  все ненужное (включая пробелы\табуляции\переносы строк это уменьшит размер файла), Так же можете поступить и с JS.
Если все таки хотите что бы css грузились "как попало", можете <link> с ними поместить в <body>

Comment: @naym Нет. Этого не нужно. Я сократил CSS с 750 строк до 709. Теперь мне Гугл предлагает сжатие данных. Это на Хостинге делается, да? Не подскажете как? А то я ищу ищу, но не могу найти как и где это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос точно, надо увидеть сайт. И 3.6. мб это довольно много.
В голову приходит, например
0). Посмотреть в консоли что же грузится дольше всего, и тогда думать почему.
1). Последовательно поотключать js и css, чтобы выяснить где проблема конкретнее, и от этого уже плясать
2). Сжать картинки, ну что еще может столько весить
3). Минифицировать скрипты и цсс. Специальными инструментами конечно, вроде Google Closure Compiler

Comment: www.orkhanalizade.com

Хочу включить для него сжатие с сервера. Только не знаю пока как этого добиться

Comment: Главный инструмент веб-разработчика, тот который запускается по кнопке f12, говорит нам, что сначала бы избавиться от явных ошибок, а потом думать об оптимизации

Comment: Я удалил bootstrap.js. Т.к я его не использую и при его подключении это намного подтормаживает загрузку сайта и оценка оптимизации падает с 59 на 57.

Comment: www.orkhanalizade.com - это и есть этот сайт? У меня он загрузился за 3-4 секунды, что помоему нормально при таком дизайне.